# Not sure about this Optimization question?

Tags: calculus

I am not even sure what this question is asking and how to even start solving it. Any help would be appreciated!

Toys are being sold at a uniform rate of $1500$ toys per year. The cost of carrying a toy in stock is $3$ dollars per year. When ordering toys, the merchant experiences a fixed order cost of $20$ dollars plus a variable order cost of $20$ cents per toy. Assuming that orders can be placed so that delivery occurs precisely when stock is depleted, how often should the merchant order toys as to minimize yearly costs?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean a variable order cost of $20$ cents per toy?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry! Fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost for ordering $x$ toys is $20+0.2x$.

These toys will be sold out after $\displaystyle \frac{x}{1500}$ years, and so they will cost $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{500}$ in that time to keep in stock.

So your total costs per "cycle" is $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{500}+0.2x+20$.

Then, yearly costs will be $\displaystyle \frac{1500}{x}\left(\frac{x^2}{500}+0.2x+20\right)=3x+300+\frac{30,000}{x}$.

> This is minimized when $x=100$, so the guy should order every $\displaystyle \frac{100}{1500}$ years, or $24$ days.

Comment: I see where you got $x/500$ but where did the square come from?

Comment: (x/1500) years * x toys * (3) $ per toy per year

Comment: Ah I see I didn't take into consideration that it was 3 dollars PER toy. Thank you so much :)